# What does T::* mean in template's parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming, type-deduction

Following the article written in [here](https://jguegant.github.io/blogs/tech/sfinae-introduction.html):

I came across this code (shortened and changed for clarity):

```cpp
template <class T> struct hasSerialize
{
    // This helper struct permits us to check that serialize is truly a method.
    // The second argument must be of the type of the first.
    // For instance reallyHas<int, 10> would be substituted by reallyHas<int, int 10> and works!
    // reallyHas<int, &C::serialize> would be substituted by reallyHas<int, int &C::serialize> and fail!
    // Note: It only works with integral constants and pointers (so function pointers work).
    // In our case we check that &C::serialize has the same signature as the first argument!
    // reallyHas<std::string (C::*)(), &C::serialize> should be substituted by 
    // reallyHas<std::string (C::*)(), std::string (C::*)() &C::serialize> and work!
    template <typename U, U u> struct reallyHas;

    // We accept a pointer to our helper struct, in order to avoid to instantiate a real instance of this type.
    // std::string (C::*)() is function pointer declaration.
    template <typename C>
    static char&
    test(reallyHas<std::string (C::*)(), &C::serialize>* /*unused*/) { }
};
```

So this

```
std::string (C::*)()
```

caught my attention.

Can anyone explain me the `C::*` part? That is a function pointer that returns `std::string` but what more?

Comment: A pointer to member function

Comment: [Pointer to member function](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members)

Comment: a pointer to a member function

Comment: A pointer to a member function.

Comment: pointer to a member function

Comment: It could be a pointer to a member function, possibly. I'll ask around and see if anyone knows.

Comment: Thanks guys :) I appreciate the feedback: I can either close it or accept an answer if one of you decides to post it.

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/264088/2069064) for an explanation of what's actually going on in this code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A member function pointer to a member in class C that returns a `std::string`.

Check [isocpp.org](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members) for more info on pointers to member functions.